# How does the ECPoint coordinate system work in Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I've some question on the ECPoint calculations within the Bouncy Castle library.

What does the ECPoint `normalize` function do?

And what is the difference between coordinate getters (`getAffineXCoord`, `getXCoord`, `getRawXCoord`)?

Comment: From the comment: "Normalization ensures that any projective coordinate is 1, and therefore that the x, y coordinates reflect those of the equivalent point in an affine coordinate system."

Answer (score 2):

Elliptic curves calculations can be performed using different methods. One method is to use projective coordinate system, which uses X, Y and Z. This system makes EC calculations faster.

This differs from the normal coordinate system where just X and Y are used and Z is set to the value 1. The `normalize` function calculates the affine X and Y for which Z is set to one.

It is of course possible to perform the normalization after each calculation but that would slow down the system; it is possible to use the projective coordinates for the next calculations.

---

The `getAffineXCoord()` and `getAffineYCoord` functions are simply used instead of `getXCoord()` and `getYCoord()` to make sure that the non-normalized X and Y aren't used - throwing an exception if this isn't the case.

Otherwise the result may not correct if Z is other than 1, for instance when X is used as outcome of a Diffie-Hellman key agreement. So you are advised to use those functions to retrieve the final result after all calculations have finished.

---

The different curve systems seem to use a curve specific coordinate system. If you use a binary curve over F(2^m) then the implementation will have code to derive the coordinates from the "raw" coordinates. These coordinates are retrieved from the `getRawXCoord` and `getRawYCoord` calls. Those are made `final` so they cannot be overridden in subclasses. The prime curves over F(p) do not override the `getXCoord` or `getYCoord` calls.

Personally I think they are implementation specific and should not have been made `public`. There are however other classes in different packages that use them, so the choice can be defended. In a modular system (since Java 9) you'd probably make them module specific.

---

More information about why projective coordinates are used can be found [here (Nayuki.io)](https://www.nayuki.io/page/elliptic-curve-point-addition-in-projective-coordinates) and more info about `normalize` can be found [here on cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47079/1172) (note the person asking the question).